# A question about rolls

Tags: probability

A dodecagon labelled by 12 months at each edge is rolled in a game. One “turn” of the game is to roll it until one April appears, then the number of the rolls is recorded. What is the probability to have five consecutive turns with rolls no greater than 10?

Could you help me with this stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It currently doesn't make any sense to me. The dice is labeled with months, so what does 10 have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the chance you don't get April on one roll? The chance you don't get April on one turn is the tenth power of this. The chance you get  $10$ or less is one monus this. the chance you get five in a row $10$ or less is the fifth power of that. I get somewhat less than $7\%$

Comment: OP's question is "What is the probability to have five consecutive turns with rolls no greater than 10?". I don't know what 10 means, since the dice is labelled by months and not numbers. The talk about April seems misleading to me.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: I took it to be not rolling April in less than $10$ tries five times in a row

Comment: I have a different interpretation, namely the probability that you don't get November or December in 5 rolls. OP will have to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean the answer is: (1-(11/12)^10)^5

Comment: @CalvinLin:  Sorry, the chance that you get April within 10 tries, 5 times in a row

Comment: @user98022:  that is correct.

Comment: @ross his probability is very close to 1. I would disagree with it, even if you take the complement.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that April is $4$.

If we can find the probability $p$ that a turn ends before getting a number $\gt 10$, our answer will be $p^5$.

The values other than $4$, $11$, and $12$ are irrelevant to the question. The event "$11$ or $12$" is twice as likely as the event "$4$."

The probability $p$ of rolling a $4$ before $11$ or $12$ is therefore $\frac{1}{3}$.